# Wamta API Parsing Error

Tags: ruby

I am trying to parse this code provided by WAMTA. It's giving me following error. Can anyone help me?

Once i try to execute, it gives me error. Also can anyone help me with with loading json objects?

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/{All}')

uri.query = URI.encode_www_form({
   # Specify your subscription key
   'api_key' => 'I have the key.',
})

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

# Basic Authorization Sample
# request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'


response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    http.request(request)
end

puts response.body  



/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:66:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): https://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/{StationCodes} (URI::InvalidURIError)
    from /Users/manshu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
    from /Users/manshu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
    from /Users/manshu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:713:in `URI'
    from data.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use:

https://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/{All}

instead of

https://api.wmata.com/StationPrediction.svc/json/GetPrediction/All

as documented on https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/547636a6f9182302184cda78/operations/547636a6f918230da855363f/console.